# Python script for comparing Excel files doesn't generate the expected results. Seeking help to resolve the issue - Debugging

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Description:

Developed a Python script to scrape data from a website, save it to an Excel file, and compare it with a previously saved Excel file. However, the comparison step fails to detect price changes accurately. Seeking assistance to identify and fix the problem.

Problem:

The script successfully scrapes food names and prices, saves the data to Excel, and compares it with a previous file based on the 'Name' column. However, the comparison fails to recognize price changes, even when they exist.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Arsalanmousavi/2fa1cbc191d2bd2655112cd3823fe8f5) is the code.

Actions Taken:

1- Used Selenium and Regex to extract food names and prices from the website.

2- Created DataFrames for the new and previous data, adding the date to the new DataFrame.

3- Saved the new data to an Excel file.

4- Loaded the previous data from the most recent Excel file in the directory.

5- Merged the previous and new data on the 'Name' column.

7- Compared the 'Price_previous' and 'Price_new' columns to detect price changes.

8- Calculated the percent change and saved changes to a separate Excel file if they were found.

9- However, the script fails to capture price changes accurately, overlooking differences between the two files.

Seeking guidance and suggestions to address the issue and ensure proper detection of price changes. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community I have shared the code in the link.